# DaVinci Resolve Python 3.6 not found

Tags: davinci-resolve, linux

I'm trying to run some basic scripts on Linux (Debian), however no python can be found.

[image: davinci resolve python]

Both Python 2 and 3 are present on the system.

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.18
```

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.8.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on `strace` is seems that `fuscript` binary searches for `libpython2.7.so` and `libpython3.6.so`

```
$ /opt/resolve/libs/Fusion/fuscript -l py3

DaVinci Resolve Script Interpreter
Copyright (C) 2005 - 2020 Blackmagic Design Pty. Ltd.

ERROR: Language 'py3' is not available.
```

E.g. on Debian based systems this could be installed, if you're lucky and the exact version is available for your distribution.

```
sudo apt install libpython3.6
```

The binary looks into several paths one of them is `/usr/local/lib/libpython3.6.so`. According to documentation this could be configured by `PYTHONPATH` env variable. However it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) any Python version can be installed (we need shared libraries - `*.so` files):

```
env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" pyenv install 3.6.11
```

then create a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s $HOME/.pyenv/versions/3.6.11/lib/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.6
sudo ln -s $HOME/.pyenv/versions/3.6.11/lib/libpython3.so /usr/local/lib/libpython3.6.so
```

Finally console should be working (Resolve will need a restart):

```
$ /opt/resolve/libs/Fusion/fuscript -l py3 -i

DaVinci Resolve Script Interpreter
Copyright (C) 2005 - 2020 Blackmagic Design Pty. Ltd.

Cannot read termcap database;
using dumb terminal settings.
Py3>
```

Comment: How would this work on a Mac?

Comment: It should work the same way, just use `brew install pyenv`. See pyenv documentation.

Comment: Is it possible with PYTHONHOME variable? I have found this post from bmd staff:
https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=141012#p759128

Comment: @Tombart how to list the paths in which dr looks for the python3.6?

Comment: PYTHONPATH in documentation is said in context of launching the python script located not in expected standard direcrories. So it looks like not ralated to path itself for python3.6.

Comment: In macOS: either use the official Python.org installers, or symlink your homebrew installed python3 into /usr/local/bin/python3. See https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=179227